# Bayesian Model For Churn

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, churn

I need to evaluate how long a customer stays with the company given a retention offer she accepted $r\in\{r_1,\dots,r_k\}$

I'd like to use Bayesian inference for modelling churn.

What prior distribution should I choose to model churn rate ?

Comment: What is the likelihood you intend to use?

Comment: I think that exponential makes the best sense